# Using TortoiseSVN on a Linux directory mapped as a Windows drive: Getting errors ' not a working copy'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN. I have a Linux directory mapped as a Windows drive. Commits and updates are working fine. I have the following problems.

1. When I do `svn info` on a Linux box, it gives me an error saying Error '.' is not a working copy
2. When I try to merge a changelist from another branch, it gives me an error saying Error '.' is not a working copy.

When I checkout code that becomes the working copy. Where is this coming from?

Answer (score 2):

Using working copy with different clients is not supported by svn:

> **[Can I use different Subversion clients with the same working copy?](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#multiclients)**
>
> You must also be sure that all the clients are built for the same OS.
>   Client compatibility is only guaranteed for a particular OS type and
>   metadata representations may differ. You must not use a native Windows
>   client and the Cygwin client on the same working copy. And if you
>   share a working copy over a network you must not use a Linux and a
>   Windows client on the same working copy.